# How to add padding in two widgets positioned vertically with in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, padding

I am working in libgdx, I have three containers c1,c2,c3.
 C1 is above c2 and c2 is above c3..

> My code is like this
> maincontiner.add(c1)
> maincontiner.add(c2)
> maincontiner.add(c3)
>
> Now I need to add some space between c2 and c3.  So what I do is that, I add **padTop** while adding c3; for ex
> maincontiner.add(c3).padTop(10)

But doing this affects the position of c1,c2. Why is that? When I am padding to c3, should the above two containers be moves as well? Is there any way to avoid their movement?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `row()` method after each `add` to place containers one above one:

```
    maincontiner.add(c1).row();
    maincontiner.add(c2).row();
    maincontiner.add(c3).padTop(10).row();
```

Please refer [this](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout) article to undetstand how table layout works.